# I have a line of text which is X px wide. The background color is X px wide aswell. How do I extend the background color so its longer than the text?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add a line of text and the background color should be the full with of the website.

I wanted to center a text in the website. I gave the text a specific width which makes it centered. Although the background color is just as wide as the text and I want to extend that

```css
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6eef2;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 1222px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.topbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #06507f;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topbar">
            <span>Lidl-Reisen.de - ... einfach urlaubiger!</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/verantwortung">Verantwortung</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/geschichte">Unternehmen</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/karriere">Karriere</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.lidl-reisen.de/faq">Service & Hilfe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the website im refering to:  https://www.lidl-reisen.de/asd

I want to recreate the topbar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recreate that navigation bar, you should have used position as absolute, so that you dont get the extra margins, though you can fix that without using that. 
Code:
HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="topbar">
            <span>Lidl-Reisen.de - ... einfach urlaubiger!</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/verantwortung">Verantwortung</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/geschichte">Unternehmen</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.lidl.de/de/karriere">Karriere</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.lidl-reisen.de/faq">Service & Hilfe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e6eef2;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    padding:10px;
}

.topbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    color: #06507f;
}
```

Check out my js fiddle link : https://codepen.io/djmayank/pen/PooZrKo